# Phantom crashes after 222 page crawls

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have an array of 262 links within a site. I am using [Phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) in a NodeJS server to crawl each of these pages to create HTML snapshots. I am finding after the 222nd page, phantom crashes with the following error:

```
phantom stderr: 2015-06-10 11:44:20.159 phantomjs[4474:58792] Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable.
```

This has happened twice now, and is a real pain as it takes quite a while for it to crawl this many pages. For the record, when I had less pages, I never came across this issue, and for the first 222 pages there are no errors, so I don't think the issue is with my current code. However I will happily post some if anyone thinks it will be useful to help me solve this problem.

My initial assumptions are it is either a bug in phantom, something to do with a maximum number of pages allowed to be crawled, or a setting I can/should add to my instances of phantom.

I found someone with the same problem which didn't get solved here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/KpDisQL7wxs

The code looks like this:

```
var crawlPage = function(arr, idx){


  // start/end crawl
  // --------------------------------

  if (!idx) idx = 0;
  if (idx >= arr.length) return;
  else if (idx === 0) console.log("Starting page crawl");


  // visit page
  // --------------------------------

  phantom.create(function(ph){
    ph.createPage(function(page){
      page.open(arr[idx], function(status){

        //error accessing page
        if (status !== "success") return console.log("Unable to access page");

        //wait 4s for page to render
        setTimeout(function(){

          //evaluate page html
          page.evaluate(function(){ 
            return document.all[0].outerHTML;
          }, function(snapshotHTML){

            //strip script tags from html
            snapshotHTML = snapshotHTML.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, "");

            //save snapshot to file
            saveSnapshot(arr[idx], snapshotHTML); //save snapshot file

            //crawl next page
            crawlPage(arr, idx+1);

            //exit page
            ph.exit();

          });

        }, 5000);

      });
    });
  });

}

var siteLinks = [/*array of 262 links*/];
crawlPage(siteLinks);
```

Comment: I used C#, Selenium, Google Chrome and nunit to do the same with more performance. It was clear when object memory was free to be garbage collected and I did not have this problem. In your case you have no code to inspect therefor I can only assume what the problem might be.

Comment: Well, does it depend on the 223th page? Have you tried to only do this for that page? If there is no problem with the single page, it's probably memory leak error. You will need yo show your code.

Comment: OK I'm just running one more crawl, if there error happens again I will try that individual page, if still an error, I will post the code.

Comment: OK, it's crashed again at about the same point, but this time the array order was different so the 222nd page was different. I also tried running the crawl on that individual page and it worked fine. So must be a bug in Phantom or memory leak or something. I will post code.

Comment: That code should be fine. 1. Can you check whether the is are most only two PhantomJS instances at any given time? 2. Will it lead to scraping problems when you reuse the `page` instance? I mean do some of the URLs point to the same domain where you need different sessions?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't think there's ever 2 instances because the function isn't called again until all processing is done and the `ph.exit()` command is made. So the first phantom finishes when the next one begins. The same is true for `page` instance. It doesn't create a new one until the previous one finishes. If this were a problem, wouldn't it crash after the 1st page crawl anyway?